# Angularjs + directive file html content click event not working in js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in angular js,

Now try to split the templates like, header,footer,leftmenu etc..

Here i added the example for left menu.

The left menu have id=sidebar-menu". Once click the sidebar-menu need to do some action.

But that respective js have in custome.js

The "sidebar-menu" click event not working.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="nav-md" ng-app="myApp" >
        <div class="container body">
            <div class="main_container">
                <div left-menu></div>
                <!-- top navigation -->
                <div top-navigation></div>
                <!-- /top navigation -->
            </div>
            <script src="vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="custom.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'views/login.html',
        controller : 'userController'
    }).when('/register', {
        templateUrl : 'views/register.html',
        controller : 'userController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/login'
    });
}]);
app.directive('leftMenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        templateUrl : "left-menu.html",
        replace : true
    };
});
```

custom.js

```
$(function () {
    $('#sidebar-menu li').click(function () {

        alert("Ddd");
        if ($(this).is('.active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('ul', this).slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('nv');
            $(this).addClass('vn');
        } else {
            $('#sidebar-menu li ul').slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('vn');
            $(this).addClass('nv');
            $('ul', this).slideDown();
            $('#sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });

});
```

left-menu.html

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" >
    <div class="menu_section">
        <h3>General</h3>
        <ul class="nav side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="index3.html">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="form_advanced.html">Advanced Components</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I understand the error I loaded js files in first then html content load in directive method.

Comment: Your problem is quite clear. Can you add plunker/jsfiddle? So we can see the error.

Comment: Since you are new with angular, you may not know the framework's capabilities, but you should try rewriting this without using your `custom.js` jQuery code at all. Angular has built in directives such as `ng-class` that can handle most of what you're doing.

Comment: @SteamDev - Yes I understand the ng-class.   Because i am working on existing project. So i tried to use existing method. Its possible to do like that my way?

Comment: Also I using some jquery plugins in that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get rid of custom.js then add a "nav" directive tag like so:

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" >
    <div class="menu_section">
        <h3>General</h3>
        <nav></nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then build the nav.html

```
<ul class="nav side-menu">
  <li ng-click="">
    <a href="index3.html">Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="form_advanced.html">Advanced Components</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then create the nav directive

```
app.directive('nav', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: 'nav.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.find('li').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this); // optimize

        if ($this.is('.active')) {
            $this.removeClass('active');
            //$('ul', this).slideUp(); ? not sure what you're doing here?
            $this.removeClass('nv');
            $this.addClass('vn');
        } else {
            $this.find('ul').slideUp();
            $this.removeClass('vn');
            $this.addClass('nv');
            //$('ul', this).slideDown(); ? not sure what you're doing here?
            element.find('li').removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
      }); 
    }
  }
});
```

I haven't tested the code but this is the gist of what you need to do.

When you need to manipulate the dom you should create a directive and use the "link" function which will pass a scope, element (a light jquery wrapped dom element of the directive) and attributes. From there you can perform the tasks needed. Also be sure to have a global jQuery object '$', angular does come with a jqLite version as angular.element *not to be confused with the 'element' passed in your link function, however the lite version doesn't have all the bells and whistles you may need.